# How to add hyperlink in table (or array) in a Google Doc using Google DOC API Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-docs

I am having the following code for appending table in Google Docs.

```
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of spreadsheet'); 
var rawData =  sss.getDataRange().getValues()    

var data = []  
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length; i++){
tempData=[]
tempData=[rawData[i][1],rawData[i][2],rawData[i][3]]
data.push(tempData)

}
var someDoc = DocumentApp.openById(someId);
var body = someDoc.getBody();

body.appendTable(data).editAsText().setBold(false);
```

This code works fine. The problem is that there is url in `rawdata[i][3]`. It gets displayed in Google doc as plain text. How can I convert it into hyperlink? It would be even better if it is possible to write it as `body.appendParagraph("my link").setLinkUrl("http://www.google.com")`. The problem is that it is in an array, not in paragraph.

Comment: Hyperlinks are properly displayed in Sheets.  The data from sheets is getting fetched into an array. The array is appended as table in Google Docs. The problem is to display hyperlinks in appended table in Google Doc.

Comment: where are you getting the links from in your code? is the text the link as well?

Comment: They are manually typed urls. If one simply type url in Google sheets, it get converted into hyperlink automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put a table to Google Document by retrieving the values from Google Spreadsheet.
- In your Spreadsheet, the column "D" has the hyperlinks. And, you want to set the value as the hyperlink.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of spreadsheet'); 
var rawData = sss.getDataRange().getValues();
var data = []
for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
  tempData = []
  tempData = [rawData[i][1], rawData[i][2], rawData[i][3]]
  data.push(tempData)
}
var someDoc = DocumentApp.openById(someId);
var body = someDoc.getBody();

// I modified below script.
var table = body.appendTable(data);
for (var r = 0; r < table.getNumRows(); r++) {
  var obj = table.getCell(r, 2).editAsText();
  var text = obj.getText();
  if (/^https?:\/\//.test(text)) obj.setLinkUrl(text);
}
table.editAsText().setBold(false);
```

- When this script is run, a table is put using the values retrieved from Spreadsheet. And, about the column "C" of the table, the text is changed to the hyperlink.

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your values of column "D" are like `https://###` and `http://###`. Please be careful about this.
- If you want to give the specific text (for example, `click here`) with the hyperlink, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      if (/^https?:\/\//.test(text)) obj.setLinkUrl(text);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      if (/^https?:\/\//.test(text)) obj.setText("click here").setLinkUrl(text);
    ```

#### References:

- [getCell(rowIndex, cellIndex) of Class Table](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#getcellrowindex,-cellindex)
- [setLinkUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setlinkurlurl)

Comment: Is it possible to add link text as well such as "click here"?

Comment: @mathsbeauty Thank you for replying. About `Is it possible to add link text as well such as "click here"?`, it's yes. In that case, please modify the above proposed script from `if (/^https?:\/\//.test(text)) obj.setLinkUrl(text);` to `if (/^https?:\/\//.test(text)) obj.setText("click here").setLinkUrl(text);` and test it again. For this, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to make all URLs in a Google Doc clickable:

```
function urlClickable() {
  var urlRegex = 'http[s]?:\/\/[^ ]+';
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('yourDocId');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var urlElement = body.findText(urlRegex);  

  while (urlElement != null) {    
    var text = urlElement.getElement().asText();

    var startOffset = urlElement.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = urlElement.getEndOffsetInclusive();

    text.setLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffset, getUrl(text.getText()));

    urlElement = body.findText(urlRegex, urlElement);
  }
}

function getUrl(text) {
  var startOffset = text.indexOf('http');
  var endOffset = text.indexOf(' ', startOffset);

  if (endOffset === -1) {
    endOffset = text.length;
  }
  return text.substring(startOffset, endOffset);
}
```